# Execute seamlessly Robocopy within a Power shell script Gui is launched(!)

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Trying to use Powershell to backup some large dir -newbie

I can't make this line to work

```
"C:\Robocopy\RoboCopy.exe" $source $destination "/E /R:10 /W:5 /V /ETA"
```

Robocopy at best (depending on the " i put here or there..) is executed but it's  its GUI that is launched (and nothing more is done).

There's no issue with the $dest and $source (I manage to log into a txt file and his is working)

Thank you

Comment: Do not quote the parameters starting at `/E`. Just put them after the `$destination` variable without quotes.

Comment: thank you but  still not working..

Comment: Quoting all the parameters the way you were doing it _definitely_ won't work, because that means you are passing that entire quoted string as a _single_ parameter. When you say "still not working," you need to be specific about _how_ it is not working. Open a PowerShell prompt and type the command, and observe the behavior.

Comment: Also, to run a quoted executable name in PowerShell, you must prefix the quoted string command with the `&` (call) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
& "C:\Robocopy\RoboCopy.exe" $source $destination /E /R:10 /W:5 /V /ETA
```

The `&` (call) operator is required if you want PowerShell to run a quoted string as a command.

In this specific case, the quotes are not needed because the executable's path and filename don't contain spaces, so you can just write this instead:

```
C:\Robocopy\RoboCopy.exe $source $destination /E /R:10 /W:5 /V /ETA
```

But is `robocopy.exe` really sitting in `C:\Robocopy`? Do you have that directory name? `Robocopy.exe` is a tool that comes with the OS and should already be in the path. Why not just this?

```
robocopy $source $destination /E /R:10 /W:5 /V /ETA
```